# Why does this hold?

Tags: fractions

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=1-\frac{1}{n+2}$$
I have tried WolframAlpha but I don't get any step by step solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you can immediately see that, at least the terms $(n+1)$ cancel out? Do you see it?

Comment: Assuming $n+1\neq0$, you can cancel $n+1$ from the denominator and numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It holds as long as $n$ is a real number different from $-1$ and $-2$.
$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{n+1}{n+2} = \frac{n+1+1-1}{n+2} = \frac{n+2-1}{n+2} = \frac{n+2}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+2} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}=\frac{n+2-1}{n+2}=\frac{n+2}{n+2}+\frac{-1}{n+2}=1-\frac{1}{n+2}
$$